# Is this abuse of casting?

Tags: java, casting

I have a list of some object

```
List<MyObject>
```

But I know it to be a list of some object that inherits from MyObject

```
List<ChildObject>
```

Trying to cast from one to the other gives me an "Unconvertible Types" warning. However, if I first cast to object and then cast to a list cast to the second type then the warning goes away

```
List<ChildObject> myChildList = (List<ChildObject>) (Object) myObjectList
```

This seems to work fine. Is there any reason I shouldn't be doing this? Could it throw an error, is there a better way or is it considered bad practice?

Comment: Apart from casting, did you run and check this programm?

Comment: Does it work at runtime?

Comment: Can you return List<? extends MyObject> where you are returning List<MyObject> now? This would provide for avoiding typecasts

Comment: This actually runs as a program and doesn't produce any bugs as far as I can see. I haven't tried <? extends MyObject> so I'll see if I can get that to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any reason I shouldn't be doing this?

Generic type parameter on the list is there to help compiler do type checking for you at compile time. Casting throws away this check, moving the check to run time.

> Could it throw an error?

Yes, it could, if the list contains objects other than `ChildObject`. The worst part is that the cast could fail in some entirely unrelated place, where your code has no cast at all.

For example, if you do this

```
// Do the hack; 
List<ChildObject> myChildList = (List<ChildObject>) (Object) myObjectList;
...
// Iterate over your list
for (ChildObject c : myChildList) {
    ...
}
```

In the example above, if `myObjectList` has some classes other than `ChildObject`, there would be a class cast exception at runtime. However, it would happen in the header of the `for` loop, not at the point where you have your cast.

> Is there a better way, or is it considered bad practice?

A better way would be creating a collection of `ChildObject`s, and populating it with the content of the original array.

Comment: Would creating a new collection and populating not be much less efficient though? That's what I wanted to avoid doing.

Comment: @publicstaticvoid Efficiency would be a concern only in the most extreme cases - for example, when your collection has thousands of items, or when you perform this operation hundred times per second. If it is one of these situations, though, you would probably benefit from refactoring your data structure a little - for example, by segregating your subclasses by type into separate lists, or by caching the results of a conversion for use in future calls.

Comment: These objects actually are segregated in most cases. The reason I have a list of objects of a more generic class is because I have database access objects etc. that are generalised to the more generic type. I'll try to find a concrete (excuse the pun) example, but does this imply that there's something wrong with how my code is structured?

Comment: @publicstaticvoid It's hard to say without looking at the specifics, but chances are that your database access layer may benefit from a small refactoring: perhaps instead of methods that look like `List<MyObject> getChildObject()`  it should have `List<ChildObject> getChildObject()` wrapping a call to generic `<T> List<T> getMyObjectSubclass(Class<T> subclass, String tableName, ...)`. This way you would get a nice-looking type-specific interface fronting a generic implementation, avoiding code duplication.

Answer (score 3):

Return `List<? extends MyObject>` where you are returning `List<MyObject>` now. This would provide for avoiding typecasts

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while `MyObject` and `ChildObject` are related, `List<MyObject>` and `List<ChildObject>` are not, that's why you get the error.

Your casting solution works, but it throws type safety out the window, which can lead to bugs. The correct way of doing the transition from `List<MyObject>` to `List<ChildObject>` is to define the list with a wildcard:

```
    //From Child to parent
    List<? extends ChildObject> child1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<? extends MyObject> parent1 = child1;

    //From parent to child
    List<? extends MyObject> parent2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<? extends ChildObject> child2 = (List<? extends ChildObject>) parent2;
```

You can read more about it in [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) Java tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you could do what you want to do without casting then this is an abuse of casting. If the result of your casting causes a run-time error then this is an abuse of casting.

Since generics was added to Java, casting is mostly unnecessary - casting should be kept to a minimum because it hides errors that could be found at compile time until run time.

Answer (score 0):

Generics were primarily designed for safe type checking at compile time. And they should not really be mixed with casting as casting pospones this type-safety check to runtime. Consider the following example where `Vehicle` is a base class extended by various classes: `Bike`, `Car` etc.

```
List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
vehicles.add(new Bike("Yamaha"));
vehicles.add(new Car("VW"));
vehicles.add(new Car("BMW"));

List<Car> cars = (List<Car>)(Object)vehicles;
for (Car vehicle : cars) {
      System.out.println(vehicle.getType());
}
```

Here I am only iterating over `List<Car>` but you can see that this program can lead to fatal errors as the first item is not a `Car` but a `Bike`.